# IF statement to color Datagridview rows bound to a SQL query

Tags: sql, vb.net, winforms, if-statement, datagridview

Alright, maybe I'm missing something simple but I can not get an if statement inside a for loop to color a datagridview row based on a cell's value. Maybe you guys can see something I can't.

Here is my SQL code:

```
SELECT 
    Part,
    CASE 
       WHEN missing = 1 OR secondmissing = 1 
          THEN '1'
       WHEN missing IS NULL AND secondMissing IS NULL 
          THEN '0'
    END AS 'missing'
FROM 
    TableA
```

This query returns a list of part numbers and if they have been marked as missing or not and appears to run fine. In my Winforms application, I have a `For` loop to check the datagridview loaded with the SQL query above to color any rows yellow that have the missing marked as 1. However nothing I seem to try work for catching line items marked as 1.

Here is my VB code:

```
For x as integer = 0 to DataGridView1.rows.count - 1
  With Datagridview1.rows(x)
    if .cells(1).value.tostring = "1" then *
       .DefaultCellStyle.Backcolor = Color.Yellow
   else
       .DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White
   End If
 End With
Next
```

Notice in the for loop I marked a line with an *. Here are all the things I have tried here.

```
if .cells("missing").value = True Then
if .cells(1).value.tostring = "1" Then
if CInt(.cells(1).value) = 1 Then
if CInt(.cells(1).value.tostring) = 1 Then
```

None of the above options seem to work. If I try and use the column name "missing" instead of the column integer of 1 it completely misses the code.

Any help would be great.

EDIT:

I guess I should note the SQL columns datatypes: `Part` is `NVARCHAR(25)` and both `missing` and `secondmissing` are `BIT`.

Comment: There is no reason to loop thru the DGV rows - since there is no guarantee that the user will ever look at all the rows it can be very wasteful depending on how many rows there are.   Use the RowPrePaint evnet or the CellFormatting.  Gobs and gobs of examples here

Comment: @Plutonix Was "here" supposed to have a hyperlink? Also, I was using the rowpostpaint event and it was causing terrible lag issues on the user end. But I was running an sql query to look up each row so that was way too process heavy. Would this lag be alleviated due to the fact that its simply reading a cell for each row instead of running a full on sql query?

Comment: No link - Google makes that sort of thing trivial.  I can guess why the lag, but for starters it should be the `RowPrePaint` event - if you are going to possibly change the color dont you want to do so *before* the row is panted?

Comment: @Plutonix I got the rowprepaint event running. A quick question on this event. I am updating the datagridview as operators mark parts complete or missing as well as updating the DGV every 5 minutes. Will this event fire on these updates?

Comment: It fires before a row needs painting.  I know it works with an actual refresh to the DataSource, not sure what you mean by "updating" the control.

Comment: @Plutonix If two operators are working on the same list of parts for a specific job number across the facility they need to know what the other operator as completed. Therefore every 5 minutes I run a refresh even that reloads the datagridview with the initial SQL query.

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with aspects of multi user systems.  The basic NET DB providers provide the means to do an actual refresh which are smoother and less involved than the hard reset you seem to be describing.  Depending on the DB there may also be notification methods available..